# How can I make my arrows invisible by setCurrentItem method of Viewpager?

Tags: android

In Oncreate of my MainActivity I add this code:

```
mDateAreaSlider.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int arg0) {

                    // Hide right arrow if reach last position 
                    if (arg0 == adapter.DateList.length - 1) {
                        mButtonNext.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        mButtonBack.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }

                    // Hide left arrow if reach first position 
                    else if (arg0 == 0) {
                        mButtonBack.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        mButtonNext.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }

                    // Else show both arrows
                    else {
                        mButtonBack.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        mButtonNext.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                ifSingding = true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });
```

and on the button click I add this code:

```
mDateAreaSlider.setCurrentItem(0);
```

but the problem is it can slide to the page I selected but does not make my arrows invisible.

**NOTE:** The 2 arrows are ImageViews in main layout,not inflated layout.So it is nothing to do with adapter.

Comment: Try using Log inside the if condition to see if the code is actually executed.

Comment: @haint No, it is not excuted

Comment: So if you manually swipe the page does the arrow go invisible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your original code with this:

```
final ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener onPageChangeListener = new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            if (position == adapter.DateList.length - 1) {
                    mButtonNext.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    mButtonBack.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }

                // Hide left arrow if reach first position 
                else if (position == 0) {
                    mButtonBack.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    mButtonNext.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }

                // Else show both arrows
                else {
                    mButtonBack.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    mButtonNext.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
};
mDateAreaSlider.addOnPageChangeListener(onPageChangeListener);
```

Execute this code on your button click

```
mDateAreaSlider.setCurrentItem(0);
mDateAreaSlider.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            onPageChangeListener.onPageSelected(0);
        }
});
```

Comment: Sorry for late reply,my connection was cut off. Btw, I tried your code and now it works with button click but not works when I slide anymore.

Comment: Oh, it is just my fault. Your code worked perfectly. Thank you so much ;)